# base64 encoding in C++

Tags: c++, node.js, encoding, base64

So i have tried to encode this string : "4ce808f16d8931a7a69548053c90144f669e765c7a227341179886461b6a9776"

this is my C++ function for base64 encoding

```
std::string Encode(const std::string data) {
            static constexpr char sEncodingTable[] = {
                    'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H',
                    'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P',
                    'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X',
                    'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f',
                    'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n',
                    'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v',
                    'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3',
                    '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '+', '/'
            };

            size_t in_len = data.size();
            size_t out_len = 4 * ((in_len + 2) / 3);
            std::string ret(out_len, '\0');
            size_t i;
            char *p = const_cast<char *>(ret.c_str());

            for (i = 0; i < in_len - 2; i += 3) {
                *p++ = sEncodingTable[(data[i] >> 2) & 0x3F];
                *p++ = sEncodingTable[((data[i] & 0x3) << 4) | ((int) (data[i + 1] & 0xF0) >> 4)];
                *p++ = sEncodingTable[((data[i + 1] & 0xF) << 2) | ((int) (data[i + 2] & 0xC0) >> 6)];
                *p++ = sEncodingTable[data[i + 2] & 0x3F];
            }
            if (i < in_len) {
                *p++ = sEncodingTable[(data[i] >> 2) & 0x3F];
                if (i == (in_len - 1)) {
                    *p++ = sEncodingTable[((data[i] & 0x3) << 4)];
                    *p++ = '=';
                } else {
                    *p++ = sEncodingTable[((data[i] & 0x3) << 4) | ((int) (data[i + 1] & 0xF0) >> 4)];
                    *p++ = sEncodingTable[((data[i + 1] & 0xF) << 2)];
                }
                *p++ = '=';
            }

            return ret;
        }
```

I get the result : "NGNlODA4ZjE2ZDg5MzFhN2E2OTU0ODA1M2M5MDE0NGY2NjllNzY1YzdhMjI3MzQxMTc5ODg2NDYxYjZhOTc3Ng=="

and for sanity check i have tried base64 encoding in a site :https://www.base64encode.org/

and i get the same result as well.

But when i tried it in nodejs :

```
var key = "�����u���H�o1P��0gnH�Fi]�N�����M�}��`a��$��(%"�$�XXt}pU";
var message = "1654503648GET/orders";

var hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', key);

// sign the require message with the hmac
// and finally base64 encode the result
var cb_access_sign = hmac.update(message).digest('base64');

console.log(cb_access_sign.toString());
```

I get different result : "TOgI8W2JMaemlUgFPJAUT2aedlx6InNBF5iGRhtql3Y="

Please help me solve this, what am i really doing wrong here ? thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the output of hmac.update()? Is it same as that input string?

Comment: in node.js you encode the binary value to base64, in your c++ code you encode a hex string representation to base64.

Comment: @kiner_shah yes

Comment: @jps so i want to encode the binary value to base64, how would i do that in C++ ?

Comment: how did you know in nodejs it was binary to base64 conversion ?

Comment: @js I have tried many sources of encoding to base64 they all get different results from that of nodejs one... I am confused... Do you have any popular libraries do this ? I need nodejs encoding format (binary to base64)... how do i do this ?

Comment: in the node.js code you call `digest('base64')`which will directly convert the binary value to base64. You can take the result `TOgI8W2JMaemlUgFPJAUT2aedlx6InNBF5iGRhtql3Y=` and convert it on https://base64.guru/converter/decode/hex and get a hex value of the the original bytes which is identical to your hex string on the beginning. Now in your C++ code you only show the encoding function. Here you could change the `data`parameter to array of byte instead of string. You didn't shwo how you call the function or how you got the string, but try get an an array of bytes instead of a hex string.